# How to move add to cart to right side bar

Tags: magento2, layout, cart

Can somebody help me to move add to cart button to right side bar in Magento 2.1.3 CE?

I succeed to move add to wish list and social icons by adding this code in   `catalog_product_view.xml` , but no success with add to cart.

Thank You.

```
<move element="product.info.social" destination="sidebar.additional" before="-"/>
```

Comment: You can take the screen shot?

Comment: Please be more specific. About which page you are talking about ? Which theme you are using ?

Comment: Product page. I use Porto theme.

Answer (score 1):

Try if this work:

```
<move element="product.info.addtocart" destination="sidebar.additional">
```

Both the `Qty` input and `Add to Cart` button are on the same block of `product.info.addtocart`.